# Configuring Spring MVC to map GET requests to one method in a controller and OPTIONS requests to another method

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-mvc, http-options-method

This would be pretty easy using annotations:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

  @RequestMapping(value="/hitmycontroller", method= RequestMethod.OPTIONS)
  public static void options(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse resp){
    //Do options
  }
  @RequestMapping(value="/hitmycontroller", method= RequestMethod.GET)
  public static void get(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse resp){
    //Do get
  }
}
```

but I can't find how to do this in XML. Is there some mapping handler that will do something like this:

```
<bean id="handlerMapping"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
  <property name="mappings">
      <mapping>
        <url>/hitmycontroller</url>
        <httpMethod>GET</httpMethod>
        <method>get</method>
        <controller>MyController</controller>
      </mapping>
      <mapping>
        <url>/hitmycontroller</url>
        <httpMethod>OPTIONS</httpMethod>
        <method>options</method>
        <controller>MyController</controller>
      </mapping>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the SimpleUrlHandlerMapping it is not possible specify the http method. Probably you have to use other mapping like the MethodUrlHandlerMapping in the Spring MVC REST project (http://spring-mvc-rest.sourceforge.net/).

The way to declare the mappings using the MethodUrlHandlerMapping should be something like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="GET /hitmycontroller">MyController</prop>
            <prop key="OPTIONS /hitmycontroller">MyController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

You can see the example in their page:

http://spring-mvc-rest.sourceforge.net/introduction.html

Look at the part 2.

Answer (score 0):

Your `@RequestMapping` annotations should work. Just delete the handlerMapping bean from your xml configuration and enable MVC annotations.

**Here is a sample configuration.** *Change base-package to the package that contain your controller classes*

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"

    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="your.package" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven>
</beans>
```